# How could I add my eclipse's workspace to git repository?

Tags: eclipse, git

I would like to add all files from eclipse's workspace to git repository. Should I manually add every single file to the repository or is there easier way to do that or they'd included automatically?

Answer (score 1):

**DON'T.**  The workspace is not portable and the plug-ins in Eclipse are only designed to handle sharing at the project level.

Create your git repository elsewhere on disk and when you create your projects, change their location to be in the repository.  Or add the Git repository to the `Git Repositories` View, physically move your existing projects into the repository while outside of Eclipse, "delete" those projects from inside of Eclipse, and then use the view to re-add them to the workpace as Eclipse is aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you try [Egit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/)

which is implementing Eclipse tooling on top of the JGit Java implementation of Git.